# Notify C# Client, when SMTP Server receive a new Email

Tags: c#, .net, email, push

I want to get all emails in my ASP.NET application that have a certain CC-recipient. To use this for future emails I didn't want to polling all the time to get them. But I can't find a way, how I can use push to get the emails instantly. Are their any frameworks in C# to help me for this?

I want to connect with my application to a mail server and register a method 'X'. Always when  a new message arrived to the mail server, my application have to be notified and my application should execute the method 'X'.

I hope that this is possible with code like this:

```
void Application_Start() 
{
    ...
    ConnectWithTheSmtpServer();
    RegisterMethodForNotification(DoSomethink);
    ...
}
void DoSomethink(Mail newMail)
{
    // Do Somethink with the mail
}
```

**EDIT:**

I did it with the [MailSystem.Net](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/). It works very fine and is very easy to implement.

Sample Code:

```
void Application_Start() 
{
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(StartIdleProcess);

    if (worker.IsBusy)
        worker.CancelAsync();

    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void StartIdleProcess(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (_imap != null && _imap.IsConnected)
    {
        _imap.StopIdle();
        _imap.Disconnect();
    }

        _imap = new Imap4Client();
        _imap.ConnectSsl(server-name, 993);
        _imap.Login(username, passwort);

        var inbox = _imap.SelectMailbox("INBOX");

        _imap.NewMessageReceived += new NewMessageReceivedEventHandler(NewMessageReceived);

        inbox.Subscribe();

        _imap.StartIdle();
    }

    public static void NewMessageReceived(object source, NewMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something with the source...
    }
```

Comment: If you want server-push functionality (realtime push, push notifications) and you want to self host then you should take a look at: * [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com)
* [XSockets](http://xsockets.net)
* [Pokin](http://pokein.com/) If you don't want to install and manage your own realtime infrastructure then you could look at [Pusher](http://pusher.com), who I work for. You could use our [.NET library](http://pusher.com/docs/rest_libraries#cs) and make a simple call to our REST API which would then push the email/notification to any listening clients. It's also worth checking out my [re

Comment: How about this implementing in a web solution ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are approaching this from the wrong angle.

SMTP does not support receiving mail (never mind PUSH mail). POP3 is what you can use for retrieving mail, but it does not have support for PUSH either (so you would have to pull for mail).

The [IMAP4 IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE) extension is what most refer to as PUSH mail - so you will need to find a library for C# that supports IMAP4 IDLE. I found some information that will get you going in the right direction (no reason to duplicate it here):

- [Using C# .Net Libraries to Check for IMAP Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545724/using-c-net-librarires-to-check-for-imap-messages-from-gmail-servers)
- [Accessing IMAP in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670183/accessing-imap-in-c)

Keep in mind when choosing a solution that it needs to support IDLE.
I really like the look of [MailSystem.Net](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/) as it fulfills your requirements.

Remember that your mail server also needs to have IMAP4 and IMAP4 IDLE enabled. Some mail servers don't support it, so you might be clean out of luck (and will have to use POP3 pulling).

Answer (score 0):

You could send a copy of your emails(i.e. using /etc/aliases file in PostFix) to a MAIL SERVER YOU CAN HANDLE. Once there, you can implement a MAIL PROCESSOR that do whatever you want anytime a mail that MEET CERTAIN CONDITIONS arrives.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with Mail processor and how can i implement it?

Comment: Look at Procmail for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using EAGetMail; //add EAGetMail namespace

namespace receiveemail
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            // Create a folder named "inbox" under current directory
            // to save the email retrie enter code here ved.
            string curpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string mailbox = String.Format("{0}\\inbox", curpath);

            // If the folder is not existed, create it.
            if (!Directory.Exists(mailbox))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(mailbox);
            }

            // Gmail IMAP4 server is "imap.gmail.com"
            MailServer oServer = new MailServer("imap.gmail.com",
                "gmailid@gmail.com", "yourpassword", ServerProtocol.Imap4 );
            MailClient oClient = new MailClient("TryIt");

            // Set SSL connection,
            oServer.SSLConnection = true;

            // Set 993 IMAP4 port
            oServer.Port = 993;

            try
            {
                oClient.Connect(oServer);
                MailInfo[] infos = oClient.GetMailInfos();

                for (int i = 0; i < infos.Length; i++)
                {
                    MailInfo info = infos[i];
                    Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}; Size: {1}; UIDL: {2}",
                        info.Index, info.Size, info.UIDL);

                    // Download email from GMail IMAP4 server
                    Mail oMail = oClient.GetMail(info);

                    Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", oMail.From.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}\r\n", oMail.Subject);

                    // Generate an email file name based on date time.
                    System.DateTime d = System.DateTime.Now;
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo cur = new
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
                    string sdate = d.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss", cur);
                    string fileName = String.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}{3}.eml",
                        mailbox, sdate, d.Millisecond.ToString("d3"), i);

                    // Save email to local disk
                    oMail.SaveAs(fileName, true);

                    // Mark email as deleted in GMail account.
                    oClient.Delete(info);
                }

                // Quit and purge emails marked as deleted from Gmail IMAP4 server.
                oClient.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception ep)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add an explanation to your solution.

Comment: There are comment in the code , explaining what each line of code does...

Comment: EAGetMail is paid software