# Executing something when the server receives an email

Tags: php, email

I have a PHP website in a managed server (I only have access through the cPanel), and I would like to execute something when an email is received, something like adding the email address and the email content to a database.

I know how to do it [with GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail) and [in ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358322/notify-c-sharp-client-when-smtp-server-receive-a-new-email), but I can't find how to do it in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish what you want:

1 - Make a script that checks a email at regular intervals and do whatever you want with the content of the email.

2 - Redirect a email account to an email processor and once again, do whatever you want with the content of the email.

As you are using cpanel the you need the to create a forwarder (email alias) and set it to the full path of the script you create to process the email with the pipe symbol | like this:

```
|/full/path/to/emailHandler.php
```

Comment: Thanks! But when I send an email I receive this: `/home/stefanom/public_html/pool/unsubscribe.php: line 1: ?php
: No such file or directory`. If I add the line `#!/usr/bin/php` it says it can't execute the file. On the cPanel I found `/usr/bin/perl` but I didn't find the php path. Any idea?

Comment: First make sure you have PHP CLI compiled, then PHP by default is installed in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin.

Comment: Now the script runs and creates a test file (just to show me that it did the job), but the sender receives an email from `Mailer-Daemon@sti.stidev.com` saying `this is a permanent error` followed by the text of the message. In the text there is no mention to the error.

Comment: Your script need to end returning 0 (zero) to the mail server.

Comment: If the script ends with `exit("this is a text");\n?>` the email contains the text followed by `------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------\n...`. If it ends with `exit`, `exit(0)` or `exit(1)` the email doesn't contain the number, but it still arrives with the same content. Is there another way to return zero?