# How to design a background job which listens to a mailbox and triggers an action when emails are received?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, email

I have recently been working on an ASP.Net MVC project where I need to trigger an action when a new email comes to my Gmail (or any other email service provider) email server.

The action I need to trigger is already implemented as a class method. And I have already made up a solution which will check for new emails (in the mail server using the Google APIs) when a user calls the method. But I want this to 'trigger' automatically.

Is there an asynchronous event handler where I can constantly check for new emails in the background and the method gets triggered when a new email pops up (e.g. SignalR)? I don't want to make use of any time-based solution like task scheduler as this will consume application pools and is ineffective. Any solutions?

Comment: You may take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358322/notify-c-sharp-client-when-smtp-server-receive-a-new-email

Comment: gmail api provides sub/pub https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

Comment: Anything you do within the context of your website will consume threads that your webserver would otherwise use. And it's not the job of a website to have a constantly running process to check your mail server. You should strongly consider setting up a completely separate application to accomplish this.