# How to validate email id before SmtpMail.Send(message) method in .net application

Tags: .net, email, smtp, mailkit

I am working in a .net application where I am sending email through smtp if the email id is not valid then also SmtpMail.Send(message) is not throwing any error, and I am getting the information of unsuccessful mail through email in sender mail id
[Please refer the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCNIn.png)

so is there any way to find the invalid email at the time of sending email so that I can warn the user about it.
[previous answer on the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342456/how-to-check-if-the-mail-has-been-sent-successfully)

Comment: There should be an API from your email service provider. Did you check that?

Comment: we are using multiple email service providers at user level. So need to handle it at smtp level.